# Sending string to serial.to_bytes not working

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to send a string variable contains the command.

Like this:

```
value="[0x31, 0x0a, 0x32, 0x0a, 0x33, 0x0a]"
self.s.write(serial.to_bytes(value))
```

The above one fails. Won't give any error.

But it's working when I send a value like this:

```
self.s.write(serial.to_bytes([0x31, 0x0a, 0x32, 0x0a, 0x33, 0x0a]))
```

I also tried sending string like this:

```
self.s.write(serial.to_bytes(str(value)))
```

Still not working. Can someone please let me know how to send the value by storing in string?

I want to do this thing:

```
value="[0x"+anotherstring+",0x"+string2+"0x33, 0x0a]"
```

and send the value.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? In Python 3 try `s.write(b"Hello")` to send a sequence of bytes instead of an unicode string.

Comment: @Dietrich i am using 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If passing a list of integers works for you then just convert your hexadecimal representations into integers and put them in a list.

Detailed steps:

1. Open a python interpreter
2. Import `serial`and open a serial port, call it `ser`.
3. Copy the code below and paste it in the python interpreter:

The code:

```
command = '310a320a330a'
hex_values = ['0x' + command[0:2],  '0x' + command[2:4],
              '0x' + command[4:6],  '0x' + command[6:8],
              '0x' + command[8:10], '0x' + command[10:12]]
int_values = [int(h, base=16) for h in hex_values]
ser.write(serial.to_bytes(int_values))
```

It will have the same effect that just this:

```
ser.write(serial.to_bytes([0x31, 0x0a, 0x32, 0x0a, 0x33, 0x0a]))
```

actually you can test that `int_values == [0x31, 0x0a, 0x32, 0x0a, 0x33, 0x0a]` is `True` so you are writing exactly the same thing.

Comment: I have this `310a320a330a` hex data converted from a string using `encode('hex')` I want to convert hex data to this: `[0x31, 0x0a, 0x32, 0x0a, 0x33, 0x0a]` and then send it as a variable to this `s.write(serial.to_bytes(value))`

Comment: That's exactly what the code in my answer does except (a) I used the name `int_values` instead of `value` for clarity, feel free to change it to your heart's content (b) I assumed your hex data is already split into individual bytes because that's how it appears to be in your question, feel free to edit it if you think something is missing.

Comment: done exactly the same thing you did, gives me syntax error on Python 2.7 @goyo

Comment: @arslion you must have done something different, I double checked and there are no syntax errors in the code I posted. Of course you will get a `NameError` if `string1`, `string2` and `self`are undefined, but no syntax errors.

Comment: string is defined already. `sendcmd=[0x+command[0:2],0x+command[2:4],0x+command[4:6],0x+command[6:8],0x+command[8:10],0x+command[10:12],0x+command[12:14],0x0D]
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid token` .This is the error

Comment: Yes, that's invalid syntax but it's not what I did. I guess you want `sendcmd=["0x"+command[0:2],"0x"+command[2:4],"0x"+command[4:6],"0x"+command[6:8],"0x"+command[8:10],"0x"+command[10:12],"0x"+command[12:14],"0x0D"]` instead.

Comment: it gave me this error: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file MKSreader1.py on line 49, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
`

Comment: Well what do you expect me to do about it? I have no idea what's in file MKSreader1.py on line 49. Anyway you should be declaring the encoding in your source code files as explained in the linked document but that has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: The code is working when i put the command directly into it. `ser.write(serial.to_bytes([0x31, 0x0a, 0x32, 0x0a, 0x33, 0x0a]))` i want to do this the other way. If you know how to, then tell me, otherwise don't do anything :)

Answer (score 4):

[serial.to_bytes](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.to_bytes) takes a sequence as input. You should remove double quotes around `value` to pass a sequence of integers instead of a `str` representing the sequence you want to pass:

```
value = [0x31, 0x0a, 0x32, 0x0a, 0x33, 0x0a]
self.s.write(serial.to_bytes(value))  # works now
```

In the first case, you sent a sequence of bytes representing `"[0x31, 0x0a, 0x32, 0x0a, 0x33, 0x0a]"`. Now, you will send the sequence `[0x31, 0x0a, 0x32, 0x0a, 0x33, 0x0a]` as expected.

---

If you want to send a string, just send it as `bytes`:

```
# Python 2
self.s.write('this is my string')
text = 'a string'
self.s.write(text)

# Python 3
self.s.write(b'this is my string')
text = 'a string'
self.s.write(text.encode())
```

And for a sequence:

```
for value in values:
    # Python 2
    self.s.write(value)

    # Python 3
    self.s.write(value.encode())
```

Comment: `str` is also a sequence... it just so happens that the representation of a list of ints with hex notation is different than the actual list itself...

Comment: I want to join multiple values like this `value="[0x"+anotherstring+",0x"+string2` how can i do this?

Comment: @JonClements yes I know that, but in this case, it is not what arslion is seeking for.

Comment: @Tiger-222 if they're only able to receive the data as a string and it's not hard-coded that way so they can remove the quote marks, then I can only guess the OP is after `ast.literal_eval` or else the answer is literally - don't send it as a string :)

Comment: So there is no other way to attach a string to a serial value?

Comment: @arslion can you clarify your needs please?

Comment: @Tiger-222 want to do this thing:  value="[0x"+anotherstring+",0x"+string2+"0x33, 0x0a]"

Comment: Updated my answer. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: @Tiger-222 I don't know how to make you understand. I have this `310a320a330a` hex data converted from a string using `encode('hex')` I want to convert hex data to this: `[0x31, 0x0a, 0x32, 0x0a, 0x33, 0x0a]` and then send it as a variable to this `s.write(serial.to_bytes(value))`