# Python - read data from QlineEdit and send as hex bytes to Serial?

Tags: python, hex, pyserial

I want convert input from QLineEdit and send to serial as Hex bytes.

Example:

QlineEdit `input` is `03040506`

Write to serial as `0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06`

Thanks,

Comment: @PM2Ring Python 3.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using [`bytes.fromhex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex)

```
data = "03040506"
out = bytes.fromhex(data)
print(out)
```

**output**

```
b'\x03\x04\x05\x06'
```

To send those bytes to the serial port, just do something like `ser.write(out)`, where `ser` is an open serial port.

Comment: I've never used `pyserial`, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39425136/4014959), you should be able to send `out`, you don't need to pass it through `serial.to_bytes`.

Comment: Yeah got it working as expected. No need to do serial.to_bytes